# Why is my drive not being encrypted with cryptsetup?

Tags: centos, lvm, cryptsetup

I have followed [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LUKS_on_LVM) in hopes of fully encrypting a secondary drive with a single filesystem over LVM on it.

Here is exactly what I have done in order:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb # goes to interactive promt (choose defaults)
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
vgcreate vg_crypt /dev/sdb1
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n storage vg_crypt
cryptsetup luksFormat -c aes-xts-plaint64 -s 512 /dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage # set passphrase
cryptsetup open /dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage storage # use passphrase
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/storage
mkdir /storage
mount /dev/mapper/storage /storage
echo "cryptdevice=/dev/vg_crypt/storage:storage root=/storage" >> /etc/default/grub
echo "storage /dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage /dev/urandom storage,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256" >> /etc/crypttab
echo "/dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage storage ext4 defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
echo "this is a test" >> /storage/test
reboot
```

Upon reboot, I have discovered that I can bypass the pass phrase input request to decrypt `/dev/sdb1` using `Ctrl ^c`. I was expecting this to prevent me from accessing the file system on `/dev/sdb`. To my surprise it is fully readable, and files show up in plain text.

Have I mis-configured something?

I've noticed this:

```
cd /storage
df .
Filesystem .....
/dev/mapper/othervg_root .... (on sda!)
```

So this directory exists on my LVM on sda. But I thought by mounting `/dev/mapper/storage` to `/storage`, I would be placing that directory on `sdb1`. Not sure what I'm missing here.

So I also noticed by logging in without the passphrase, `/dev/mapper/storage` does not exist. So I went a head and removed `/storage`, and rebooted. This time I entered the pass phrase, and found `/dev/mapper/storage`  does exist, and `/storage` does too (even though I just deleted it), but it is still on the  logical volume on `sda`. I'm so confused.

Now I noticed `lsblk` didn't have a mount point for storage. So I remounted like before. Now `df /storage` does show the file system as `/dev/mapper/storage`. I rebooted and entered the pass phrase this time. `/storage` is once again under the wrong file system. For some reason, the mounting at boot time is being done wrong. It has to be something in the etc files.

I read through man pages on /etc/*tab files and made some changes:

fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage /storage ext4 defaults 0 0 # add the '/' in /storage
```

crypttab:

```
storage /dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage none cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512
# changed size to match key in cryptsetup
# changed key to none (/dev/urandom is something particular to swap i guess)
# removed uneccesary 'storage' in key=val list. I saw 'root' in the guide and thought i needed the name of my crypto device
```

I removed the line from Grub, because I don't know what that's doing. I deleted all the LVM stuff on `sdb1` with `{lv,vg,pv}remove` commands, then deleted partition `sdb1`. I commented out the lines temporarily from the `/etc/*tab` files and rebooted.

Finally I redid the partition, the LVM scheme, the ext4 filesystem, and uncommented the 2 lines from `/etc/*tab` files.

Now when I reboot, I am getting startup problems and it's taking me to emergency mode.

`journalctl -xb` shows me a few peculiar lines:

```
.... kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
.... systemd[1]: Failed to mount /storage
```

There are other failures about dependencies for local file systems, relabeling filesystems, and migrating local SELinux policy changes. Not sure if those are entirely relevant though.

Comment: Why did you run `cryptsetup luksFormat -c aes-xts-plaint64 -s 512 /dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage` when the LV you created was named `vg_crypt`?

Comment: I'm brand new to these commands. I thought `lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n storage vg_crypt` was saying create an lvm called `storage` in the `vg_crypt` volume group. So I thought that created the `/dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage` device which acted as the logical volume.

Comment: Oh, that's right! Crap I forgot about that. I'm used to the path structure `/dev/vg_crypt/storage`. My bad. I know you can't check now, but when things are working correctly you should see a luks device nested inside of the LV which is then inside the partition when running `lsblk`.

Comment: Yeh I've used that and I see `crypt` under `TYPE`. The tree on the left looks like `sdb->sdb1->vg_crypt-storage->storage`. After I mount it with `mount /dev/mapper/storage /storage` I can see the mountpoint just fine! (I've even used the verbose `mount -t ext4`). I get no errors there so something about my `/etc/*tab` files must be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT WOOOO!

Problem is in `/etc/fstab`.

My regular `sda` partitions were being mounted like so:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_sda-root /     ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_sda-swap swap  ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_sda-home /home ext4 defaults 0 0
```

So naturally I followed the scheme and added mine:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage storage ext4 defaults 0 0
```

The problem with this line, is the first field, the *fs_spec*, as noted in the [fstab(5) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html). "This field describes the block special device or remote filesystem to be mounted."

Since crypttab is processed prior to fstab, the decrypted device is accessible as `/dev/mapper/storage`, NOT as it's original LVM mapped device name `/dev/mapper/vg_crypt-storage`.

So by changing my line in `/etc/fstab` to:

```
/dev/mapper/storage storage ext4 defaults 0 0
```

`/etc/fstab` was then mounting the proper decrypted device to `/storage`.

I have tested by rebooting and canceling the passphrase (with `Ctrl ^C` 3 times), which forces me into emergency mode. Here, the encrypted device is not present, and has to be manually decrypted and mounted.

I think I explained that clearly/correctly but please correct me anywhere I am missing something!